# Using termwise (term-by-term) differentiation on an infinite series to satisfy a differential equation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have a question which asks me to use termwise differentation on the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}$$ to show that it satisfies the differential equation $$x^2y''+xy'+x^2y=0$$

I dont understand what this question is asking me to do. I have found the interval and radius of convergence and the first 3 terms of this in previous questions if that is relevant at all?
Can someone explain this to me or the method etc so that I know how to do complete it?

Comment: If $y(x)$ is your series $\sum(-1)^n(n!)^{-2} 2^{-2n} x^{2n}$, then what is $y'(x)$ and $y''(x)$?  Does $x^2y''+xy'+x^2y$ evaluate to $0$ for every $x$?

Comment: @user10354138
Yes thats what I thought, but how do I actually find the derivative of the series? I know how to differentiate functions so is it the same method? If not, what do I have to do to the series to be able to differentiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$y(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!^22^{2n}}.$$
Since a power series can be differentiated term-by-term inside its radius of convergence, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
y'(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2nx^{2n-1}}{n!^22^{2n}}\\
y''(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2n(2n-1)x^{2n-2}}{n!^22^{2n}}
\end{align*}
$$
and they converges absolutely on the same region.  So
$$
\begin{align*}
&x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+x^2y\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2n(2n-1)x^{2n}}{n!^22^{2n}}
+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2nx^{2n}}{n!^22^{2n}}
+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{n!^22^{2n}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2n(2n-1)x^{2n}}{n!^22^{2n}}
+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2nx^{2n}}{n!^22^{2n}}
+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{(n-1)!^22^{2(n-1)}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!^2 2^{2n}}[2n(2n-1)
+2n-4n^2]x^{2n}\\
\end{align*}
$$
which is equal to $0$.

Comment: Oh okay, so only the numerator is differentiated using standard differentiation techniques? Is there a reason the denominator is not differentiated?

Comment: Also, the differential equation also has $x^2$ and $x$ terms in it. I don't have experience with differential equations so this may be obvious but how come the solution you have provided only requires adding the $y$ terms and ignoring the $x$ terms with it still equalling 0? Is this just how differential equations work?

Comment: The denominator is just a constant,  There is no ignoring $x$ term here, $xy'$ is by definition the product of $x$ and $y'$, similarly $x^2y''$.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry. I see that you show for example, in the second derivative of y term where the part of it was $x^{2n-2}$ was then $$x^{2n-2}.x^2$$ giving---> $$x^{2n}$$ .

Sorry haha I missed that one. 

Thank you very much, I do understand this now!

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question. If you have a power series, you are allowed to differentiate it termwise (within the radius of convergence), just like a polynomial. I.e.
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}
$$
Now, you can just differentiate the given series and check that it satisfies the differential equation as you would any other function.

Comment: Ah I see, so if I find the 1st and 2nd derivative of the series and plug those results straight into the differential equation given, then this should equal 0?

Comment: Will it always equal 0 or are there cases where differential equations are not satisfied?

Comment: To your first question, yes that's exactly what you should do. To your second, yes, usually one should specify a region where you want the differential equation satisfied, however, here I think you can take it to be everywhere

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: No problem! @KaylaMartin

Comment: I do have another question that I just posted about summation of series if you wouldn't mind taking a look at that too by any chance? You explain stuff very well!